# What is mean by unsigned code in signed java applet?

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I have self signed jar file. My jar file don't have any JSObject class but uses this object. When i try to run my applet i get security warning as "**Block potential unsafe components from being run?**"

I don't know which part of my applet is not signed?

Comment: Have you added the certificate you have used for signing to the browser certificate store? Browser has its own store of certificates it `does know`. But your certificate is unknown for browser. And it leads to this warning.

Comment: I am having 2 other applet signed with the same certificate and they work fine.

Comment: Then check your browser security settings. Most probably your working applets do not do sensitive things, but your third applet, tries to do something, that is not allowed by browser security settings.